# Should my header file be called from the 'store' folder in Nuxt instead of the 'components' folder?

Tags: vue.js, module, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm testing out the Vuex store implementation in Nuxt and wondered whether the Store folder is now the best way of sharing components and modules, rather than with the Components folder?

For example, I currently call the header from default.vue in the Layouts folder with this code referencing the Components folder:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Header />
    <nuxt />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from '~/components/appheader.vue'
import Footer from '~/components/appfooter.vue'
export default {
  components: { Header, Footer }
}
</script>
```

But, as far as I understand, if header.vue is in the Store folder then it can simply be called with the filename, like this below with no need to import or export it. Have I understood that correctly?

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <appheader></appheader>
    <nuxt />
    <appfooter></appheader>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the store folder should not contains components. Put your components only in `components` folder.

The `store` folder is only for [modularizing Vuex](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#modules-mode).

If you don't want to write your `import` statement in each components, you can use [nuxt-global-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-global-base-components). But I'm not convinced this is a good practice...

Also, be careful with your components name. Header and Footer are html reserved words. Name them AppHeader and AppFooter instead.